# Does guest account work like a VM (virtual machine)?

Tags: 12.04, permissions, virtualization, guest-session

If guest session creates the entire user and everything, when running, then erases it all. It sounds like a VM instance, turning on and then turning off/logging out.
Is it?

Answer (score 2):

No, the guest session is loaded in to a memory allocated space using [`tmpfs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) from pre-defined settings located in `/etc/guest-session/skel` and limited privileges, ie: a guest session cannot access anyone else's home folders.

When you logoff a guest session or reboot your computer, that temporary session and it's files are erased from memory. Any further footprints (downloads, temp files) that are stored in `/tmp` during the a guest session are erased when the computer reboots.

It is a session per se, only loaded in a way that can be discarded when you logoff / reboot your computer.